# Can I use the adjective “modest” to describe the simplicity of something?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I have a profile on GitHub and I want to say that there is nothing special or extra-ordinary in my code. My code is not simple but there are small examples, and not real big projects. So I want to say "My profile on GitHub is ...". Can I say "my profile is modest?" Or is there a better way to say that? It's a direct translation from my native language, so I'm not sure that it's the same in English.

Comment: You would probably want to identify *the way* in which it's "modest".  If you mean there's nothing world-shaking and no enormous one-person projects in your past, you could say your engineering skills are "of solid commercial quality" (which means that you have no trouble getting hired and paid for your work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By saying

> ...there is nothing special or genius in my code

You are only **being modest** if your code is actually **special or genius**, otherwise you're just saying what it is.

> My profile **is modest**

Technically means your **profile**, as **an entity**, does not use flowery language or hyperbole, but is **unpretentious**, the **low-key** attitude does not reflect on your code base.

For example, you are responsible for the latest **whiz-bang** app that has gone viral, and your profile only says

> **Ordinary Programmer**

Your **profile** is **modest**(small amount), only two words
You are **being modest**(understated), since you are much more than just an ordinary programmer
You are **being modest in your profile**

From a colloquial usage standpoint, if you say

> My Github profile is **modest**

most people will probably understand it to mean

> My Github profile and code base is **unassuming**

which is what you intend to mean since **profile** can be both the entity which is a **summary description** of yourself and what your **presence** on Github looks like